# How to compute trajectories normal to field lines?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, differential-geometry

I have function [Psi][r,z] found from solution of a Grad-Shafranov equation. Magnetic field is expressed through [Psi][r,z] as follows

```
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB][r_, z_] = {1/r \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\), -(1/
    r) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\)}
```

But I also need a function [Chi][r,z] such that its gradient is everywhere perpenticular to the gradient of [Psi][r,z]. Same magnetic field is expressed through [Chi][r,z] by

```
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]1[r_, z_] = G[\[Psi], \[Chi]] {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\)}
```

where G[[Psi], [Chi]] is a function also to be found [it is defined upto arbitrary function of [Chi]].

It is easy to draw stream lines of both [Psi][r,z]==const and [Chi][r,z]==const using StreamPlot, e.g.

```
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB][r_, z_] = {1/r \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\), -(1/
    r) \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\)}
\[DoubleStruckCapitalG][r_, z_] = {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(z\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(r\)]\(\[CapitalPsi][r, z]\)\)}
StreamPlot[{\[DoubleStruckCapitalB][r, z], \[DoubleStruckCapitalG][r, 
   z]}, {z, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {r, 0, 1}
 , AspectRatio -> Automatic
 , StreamMarkers -> None
 , StreamPoints -> Coarse
 ]
```

But I need to compute the function [Chi][r,z] itself.  Any idea will be apprecieted. I have found one method but it involves integration of a differential equations on a mesh and subsequent interpolation.

Is there any way to retreive an interpolation of streamlines drawn by StreamPlot?

Comment: `StreamPlot[]` actually does use `NDSolve[]` behind the scenes (IIRC), so you'll really need to integrate ODEs either way.

Comment: @IgorKotelnicov It is very unclear what actually do you want? From one side you ask about trajectories, and from another you are ask about function `Chi`. But you not even shown  function `[Psi][r,z]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: I need to compute \chi as function of r,z.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Do you need function `chi` in a general case, like theorem or in a particular case, like numerical code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev; I need $\chi(r.z)$ and $\psi(r,z)$ to express magnetic field, curvature of field lines and some other quantities as functions of $\chi$ and $\psi$ to study plasma stability with the help of Bernstein's energy principle. Function $\psi$ is numerically computed wiht Matlab code and can be imprted into Mathematica is table of numbers $\{r,z,\psi\}$.